# Python - cx_freeze script not working

Tags: python, cx-freeze, nonetype

I have problem with python scripts built in cx_freeze. When I run the source script  by python, everythink works. But when I run the compilled script,
it still ended with errors like: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().

Thank you for your help, 
Honza

Comment: So... there seems no problem here

Comment: No it is not, I want only to share my knowledge to save some time of someone.

Comment: @user3016712 in which case you should post it as a question, and then check the 'answer your own question' block to answer your question in a Q&A style format. As it stands this is not a question so it should not be here.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new here and i have not found any other option, how to post some knoledge here. if you can tell me where it should be i would be grateful.

I have not found here neither question for my problem nor answer. I solved the problem and I wanted to share it with community. So I´m sorry that i wanted to help someone:(

Comment: @user3016712 : You can post things like this here, but post just the problem first, and then add an answer saying how you solved it. For a new user, you might need to wait a while before it lets you answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation I found that the problem was with HOME environment variable (It has to be set).

When I set the environment variable HOME, it started to work properly.

I hope it will safe time and help somebody,
Honza

Comment: Is there a way to set the environment path from the program?